# Iframe scrollbar align to right

Tags: html, iframe

There is a way to align the scroll bar from an iframe  to right? its by default to left.
any idea?

[take a look here](http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_align) i wanna see the search box when i load the page!

i have an application that has an ifram, in the ifram I'm loading a website that the search box is on the upper right, 
 and i want that when the page loads i should be able to see the search box right away without having to scroll to the right.... something not clear?

Comment: I am pretty sure it's by default to the right...  As most people are right handed and read from left to right ...  Sounds like something is wonky with settings or code that you are seeing it on the left.  You should always add code to Stack Overflow so that we may see what you are working with.

Comment: sorry my question is, i want the scroll bar should be on the right side of the ifram when the page loads and i should have to scroll it to left!!! understand?

Comment: I am confused...fusss... :) any picture for illustration?

Comment: take a look on the link above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you use jquery? if yes, you can do the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
<div id="frame" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: scroll";>
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/default.asp" width="1024" height="768" scrolling="no">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</div>
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</p>
<p>The align attribute was deprecated in HTML 4, and is not supported in HTML 4.01 Strict DTD or in XHTML 1.0 Strict DTD. Use CSS instead.</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$("#frame").scrollTop(10).scrollLeft(750);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you copy and paste the code into a html file and open it in your browser, you'll see that the iframe is automatically scroll to the very right.

The key changes are:

1. import jquery in your html file
2. add scrolling="no" to your iframe
3. specify the width and height of your iframe, it should be roughly the same as the actualy width & height of the embedded page
4. wrap your iframe in a `<div>`, be sure to specify the width & height (less than the iframe width & height)
5. add the javascript code before the closing `</body>` tag

   `<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   $("#frame").scrollTop(10).scrollLeft(800);
   });
   </script>`

Comment: no you got me worng i need a scroll bar cuz i wanna see the wole site! the only think i need is it should be on the right site so i should be able to see the search box first! but if you set scrolling="no" i'll end up seeing only the size of the iframe no?

Comment: I modified my answer, now the iframe seems to have a scroll bar, but it's actually the scroll bar in the <div>. You can modify the width and height of the iframe if you want to see more of the page, and adjust the scrollLeft() value accordingly.