# Prescrolled element with overflow possible with CSS

Tags: html, css, position

I have a div with horizontal overflow that I can scroll horizontally.

I want that the content of this div is already scrolled all to the right and that you have to scroll to the other direction instead. Is there anything possible to do with CSS? Relative positioning wouldn't be that comfortable because the length of the div's content varies.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible with just css. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873515/iframe-scrollbar-align-to-right) is a way to do it with JQuery. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text-direction:rtl` [**Simple demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/z3kzY/)